# Google Analytics Linker plugin/cross-domain tracking

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I want to use Google Analytics to track traffic across multiple domains. Originally I had each domain set up as a separate property each with its own tracking ID. Recently though I had a problem with my code, so went to fix it and found [this info on Cross Domain Tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342) which says I need to set up one property for all my domains using the same Tracking ID.

I was following [the instructions on this site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker#overview) prior to this for the Auto Linker plugin. I thought that the way I was doing it was correct. I did fix my tracking code successfully, but I'm just a little confused as to how I should set up my properties and tracking IDs. Should I have a separate ID for each domain or do I need one tracking ID across all my domains?

Here is my current tracking ID code to track across multiple domains (of course I have the correct tracking ID where -XXXXXX-X is and I just put in example domains to show what I'm doing):

```
    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['source.com', 'destination-1.com', 'destination-2.com', 'destination-3.com', 'destination-4.com'] );
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Comment: Use a single id. The idea is that you can track visits across two domains without interrupting the session - so you need to go your data into the same property to see pageviews on both domains in the same report. You should use a filter to add the hostname to the page path, though - else pages with the same name on both domains will be conflated into one row in the reports.

Comment: Ok thanks so much. Do you by any chance have a link to a page that describes how to add the filter to do this?

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en